# JQuery Tabs and MVC Integration whilst retaining REST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been struggling with this one for a few days now and I thought I would put it out there and see if anyone can help.  I have an MVC4 Application and I'm using the JQuery Tabs as a Menu. I have implemented this by returning partial views into the tabs.  The problem  is that I have no browser history and I have not maintained the MVC RESTful pages "{controller}/{action}/{id}"  can anyone help me in figuring out if there is a way to change the URL based upon what the tab is clicked?

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Household Info", "Info", "HouseholdFees", null, new { title = "HouseholdInfo" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Household Management", "Management", "HouseholdFees", null, new { title = "HouseholdManagement" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Household Approval", "Approval", "HouseholdFees", null, new { title = "HouseholdApproval" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Household Administration", "Index", "HouseholdFeesAdministration", null, new { title = "HouseholdAdministration" })</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and

```
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                cache: false,
                spinner: 'Loading task...',
                beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
                    ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                        ui.panel.html(
                            "Loading...");
                    });
                },
                collapsible: false
            });
```

Comment: So what is wrong with the way you have it right now? Each of those action links seems like it goes to a controller action in HouseholdFees

Comment: yes it works fine but i want to be able to go http :// fsgsfgsg/{controller}/{action}/{id} and navigate to a specific tab

Comment: also see the URLS for the tabs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not really an answer Its more of an mis-understanding of the use of JS Tabs. I did't end up using the JS Tabs component at all because I think I was misusing them to try and create a menu but I did like their look and feel, so I created a new JS class that dynamically added the styling of the JS TABS component to my own menu.  I lost all the ajax bit and caching ect... but I think this was a better solution for my needs.

JS Extension:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.tabmenu = function() {

    // Plugin code
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all");
        $(this).find("ul").addClass("ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all");
        $(this).find("li").addClass("ui-state-default ui-corner-top")
            .bind('mouseenter', function () {
                $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
            })
            .bind('mouseout', function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
            });
        $(this).find("#main").addClass("ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom");
        $(this).find("a").addClass("ui-tabs-anchor");

        var parts = window.location.pathname.split("/");

        for (i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            $("a[title*='" + parts[i] + "']").parent().addClass("ui-tabs-active ui-state-active");
        }
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

In my MVC LAYOUT page I added the following code.

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#tabsmenu").tabmenu();
        });
    </script>


            <div id="tabsmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Household Info", "Info", "HouseholdFees", null, new {title = "HouseholdInfo"})</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Household Management", "Management", "HouseholdFees", null, new {title = "HouseholdManagement"})</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Household Approval", "Approval", "HouseholdFees", null, new {title = "HouseholdApproval"})</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Household Administration", "Index", "Administration", null, new {title = "HouseholdAdministration"})</li>
                </ul>


                <div id ="main">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript as an anchor/hashing solution like so. Firstly, change the hash of the URL when a tab is selected.

```
$("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function (event, ui) {
    window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
});
```

Create a function to react to the current hash:

```
function setCurrentTabFromHash() {
    $("#tabs").tabs("select", window.location.hash);
}
```

Call that function from:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setCurrentTabFromHash();
});
```

And:

```
$(window).hashchange(function(){
    setCurrentTabFromHash();
});
```

Alternatively, you could integrate Ben Alman's fabulous BBQ plugin for asynchronous browser history, as seen here:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

I hope this helps, and good luck with your app!

Comment: Thanks for your response but I was hoping to be able to navigate URLS with http :// fsgsfgsg/{controller}/{action}/{id} structure not with hashs.

Comment: What I've done to simulate it before is to use #/directory/ with "/directory/" as the hash I push. It looks more natural at least. With more modern browsers, it can be done with pushState and popState. jquery History plugin is another plugin you could use which implements just that: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js For that plugin, hashes aren't necessary at all. I hope this helps.